How to have 'Choose Browser' as an option when clicking on link?
I am building an app on Android, and the app has a web browser button that redirects to amazon.com using Google Chrome. Now I want the web browser to show me list of available browsers I can choose from.
I did the code, but somehow my Samsung Galaxy A52s doesn't trigger the choose option. I went to Settings > Apps > Default Apps and saw that Chrome is the default browser, I reset preference yet still on running the code I still didn't get the choose option. How to do it? I need help. This is the part of the code:
    // Set up button to launch the web browser with an implicit intent
    binding.implicit.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        Uri website = Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com");

        // Create an implicit intent to open the browser
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, website);

        // Use an Intent Chooser to show the available apps to handle the request
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Open with");

        // Launch the chooser with the ActivityResultLauncher
        browserLauncher.launch(chooser);
    });

    return view;
}


Steps to Ensure the Chooser Appears
Check for Installed Browsers: Ensure that you have multiple browsers installed on your device. If Chrome is the only browser, the chooser won’t appear. 
Clear Defaults for Browsers: Even after resetting preferences, sometimes individual app defaults need to be cleared. Go to Settings > Apps > Chrome > Open by default and clear defaults. Repeat this for any other browsers. 
Your code looks mostly correct, modify your code:
// Set up button to launch the web browser with an implicit intent
binding.implicit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Uri website = Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com");
    // Create an implicit intent to open the browser
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, website);
    // Use an Intent Chooser to show the available apps to handle the request
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, "Open with");
    // Launch the chooser
    startActivity(chooser);

});


I think you need to learn how to use markdown to format your posts.
